# Install an app programmatically from inner memory

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have created a small app, able to download an apk file and to install it. This app is working correctly when I install the .apk file on the sdcard, but when I try to download the file in the inner memory, I get an error : "Erreur d'analyse".

Is there a way to install an apk file that would have been installed in the inner memory and not on the sdcard?

I can understand why it wouldn't be possible on a phone. But with the new tablets and their gigs of memory, it should be possible?

Comment: what code are you using to install the apk? Just launching the PackageInstaller app? It may allow you to do that with internal storage. Also when you say internal storage do you mean like in your applications files director inside the /system/data/? or do you mean a device that has no SD but has a larger volume storage(like a xoom) much of this storage is still kind of considered external (the user can manipulate it) where internal storage the user can't touch without a rooted device.

Comment: What I am doing is reading a file from a server and write it on the tablet. When the file is written, I just create an Intent, set data and type and execute it for installation.

Comment: Post the Intent that you are using and we may be able to help more.\

Comment: Ok, I found out my mistake. I thought the getExternalStorageDirectory method only points to the SD card, but this is not the case. This function points to a part of the memory called as external.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to write it to internal memory. If there were, there would be a [Manifest Permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for it (such as `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for writing to the SD card), but unfortunately there is no such permission.